# Dynamic Data Validation in Excel (Non-VBA!)

Tags: excel, dynamic, validation

I got `n` Categories which hold `m` Products. This list is unsorted, for example like this:

[image]

Now here's what I basically want to do with this list:

1. Dropdown: Data validation which dynamically stores a list of each unique value of the first column (= I won't be able to select Category_5 since it does not exist yet).
2. Dropdown: Provide a list of all products based on the selected category in the first Dropdown.

[image]

Is there any non-VBA solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example spreadsheet layout:

- `A2:A13`         - Category list, the items are not unique
- `B2:B13`         - Product list
- `Cell D2` down - Dropdown list 1 source, unique items, dynamic
- `Cell F2` down - Dropdown list 2 item incremental number 1.. (less calculations in the formula)
- `Cell G2` down - Dropdown list 2 source, dynamic
- `Cell I2`             - Dropdown cell 1
- `Cell J2`             - Dropdown cell 2

Cell `D2`: array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> from formula window to enter, curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user), copied downwards:

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$A$13;MATCH(0;COUNTIF($D$1:D1;$A$2:$A$13);0))}
```

Gives a unique list of categories.

Cell `G2`: array formula, follow instructions  in the previous section:

```
{=INDEX($B:$B;SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$13=$I$2;ROW($A$2:$A$13);"");$F2))}
```

Gives a list of products under a category selected in cell `I2`.

The lists are not sorted: better to sort the initial lists by category and product.
No error handling: the formulae should be updated with `IF ISERROR` clause.

[Dynamic_dropdown_lists.xls](http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/Dynamic_dropdown_lists.xls)

Comment: awesome! almost thought, i'd need to realize it in VB. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work without VBA in Excel you'd need some way of resetting the range of valid entries for the data validation in Column 2 and since the source can only be a list or a range you'd have to code something to change that information when the associated Column 1 value changes.

If you don't want to go the VBA route then those kinds of activities are bread & butter for a database like Access (or maybe InfoPath) which would better suit your needs.