# How do implement dynamic data validation e.g. as Excel VBA-function?

Tags: excel, vba

Data validation in Excel is a helpful way to verify user input in Excel. The standard way is to (1) define somewhere (e.g. on an auxillary sheet) a list with possible input values and (2) then choose that range in the `Source` field. Alternatively, one can also directly type in the different options in that field, e.g:

[image: Excel Data Validatio Dialog Window]

My question: **How do we make the data-validation list dynamic?**

What I tried so far is to enter a (possibly user-defined VBA) formula returning a list of strings in into the field `Source` of the data-validation dialog, for example

```vb
=INDEX({"New","Mint","Very Good","Good","Acceptable","Poor"},{1,RANDBETWEEN(1,6)})
```

However, this approach does not work as it leads to an error message

> You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections,
>   and ranges) or array constants for Data Validation criteria.

What do I miss? Which (possibly more elegant) way of making the `Source` of the data validation dynamic do you suggest?

**Edit:** My concrete problem:

On all (but the first) tab sheet, I have a cell called `myTest` and the list of allowed values is for a cell on the first tab, where I want be able from the  list composed of all possible values of `myTest`.

**References:**

- Debra Dalgleish: *"Create Dependent Drop Down Lists"* at [contextures.com](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)
- [Dynamic Data Validation in Excel (Non-VBA!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827750/)

Comment: i did it once with a bunch of hidden columns. the hidden columns had formulas which gave different values depending on certain entries in that row. these values could then be used for data-validation in other cells in the same row.

Comment: When you say "make it dynamic", are you saying the source will change complete locations, or you want to have the last row of a source sheet dynamically found and include the data within?  Essentially, you give info about a general concept without providing any foundation for what is and what is desired in your particular case, which would lead to an opinionated or open-ended discussion, not an *answerable* question, which this forum requires.

Comment: @Cyril's comment is on-point: exactly what do you *want* to do, or are you just exploring?  If you use a VBA function as the source for a validation list, it must return a range on a worksheet, and that range must be contiguous.

Comment: @horst: Your approach does not work for my case since the length of the range of allowed values may vary.

Comment: If you just need to pick one  value from a list then you could do that with a UDF - just have it return a single cell picked at random from your list of potential responses.

Comment: How many tabs do you have?  Would all of the values fit within a hard-coded list, or would they need to be listed in a worksheet range?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have like 5 to 20 tabs, so the union of all cells called `myTest` would give a list of the same length. What do you mean by "would they need to be listed in a worksheet range"?

Comment: I believe there's a limit on the length of the comma-separated list you can paste into the DV dialog - any longer than that and you need to point it at a range instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in the first sheet's code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Const LIST_COL As Long = 26
    Dim sht As Worksheet, i As Long

    i = 1
    Me.Columns(LIST_COL).ClearContents       '<< clear current list
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets  '<< collect all the values
        If sht.Name <> Me.Name Then            
            Me.Cells(i, LIST_COL).Value = sht.Range("myTest").Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sht

End Sub
```

It will collect the values from the other sheets into a range you can reference for the validation list.

Note: if the other sheet's values are updated via code or formulas (ie. do not require you to go to each sheet to change values) then you'd need to do a bit more work.

---

**EDIT** - this is more convoluted but works more reliably, since it gets run whenever you click on the validation drop-down

**1.** Put this in a regular module (edit as required):

```
'A function to return a range containing the 
'  various values which need to appear in the validation list
Public Function ListCompile() As Range

    Const LIST_COL As Long = 26      '<< create the list in Col Z
    Dim sht As Worksheet, i As Long

    i = 1
    Sheet1.Columns(LIST_COL).ClearContents
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> Sheet1.Name Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, LIST_COL).Value = sht.Range("myTest").Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sht
    'return the list we just created
    Set ListCompile = Sheet1.Cells(1, LIST_COL).Resize(i, 1)
End Function
```

Note: I'm using the codename for Sheet1 (which might be different from the tab name).  You can see the code name in the VB editor Project Explorer.

**2.** Define a named range "tester" with "RefersTo" equal to `ListCompile()`

**3.** Finally set your data validation list range to:  `=tester`

Comment: The values of `myTest` on all sheets can actually change, so it does indeed make sense to update the list of allowed values every time the user clicks on the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming:**

- Your list is in column A
- There is no header

You could make data-validation with a dynamic list using this formula as source:

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1)
```

---

*Edit:* below is an image of an example using the formula above in data-validation applied to cell B1:

[image]

If you can somehow join your values in a single column, this is a possibility.

Comment: What exactly does your code do? I believe we might have missunderstood each other -  I am looking for some kind of trick which accumulates the values of all cells called `myTest` over about 5 to 20 different tabs (each having this `myTest`).